# Delphi XE2: Does FastMM work with Win64 application?

Tags: delphi, fastmm, delphi-xe2

I use FastMM in my Delphi application to trace memory leaking especially in FullDebugMode.  With the new release of Delphi XE2, can we use FastMM as the memory manager?  Can FastMM work with the Win64 platform?

Comment: Add `{$SetPEFlags $20}` or set the `LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE` flag for 4GB memory access instead of the default 2GB. See [FastMM faq](http://fastmm.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/fastmm/FastMM4_FAQ.txt?revision=38&view=markup).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

FastMM is pre-installed in Delphi XE2 and is the default memory manager for both Win32 and Win64 platforms, but the pre-installed version does not include all the features the open-source FastMM (available on SourceForge) provides. To use all of its features (including FullDebugMode), you have to download and install the open source project from SourceForge.

The project on SourceForge is not updated for XE2 yet; that means, for using FullDebugMode you have to wait a few more days until the open source project is updated for XE2 too.

Comment: XE2 32bit just came up, not in zip downloads, but in the SVN at http://sourceforge.net/projects/fastmm/, like 7 hours after your answer :-)

Comment: Pierre just scheduled the work for the weekend and it is not related to that questions here. I've blogged early this week about this. 64-bit FullDebugMode is different and there isn't yet an ETA.

Answer (score 6):

Pierre Le Riche committed changes to the [SVN repository](http://fastmm.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/fastmm/) yesterday to add support for both 32 and 64 bit targets of XE2.